# Cannot find module node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js after running pod install

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Starting with a fresh project (npx react-native init MyTestApp), when I run npm list @react-native-community/cli I get:

```
MyTestApp@4.1.0 /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyTestApp
└── (empty)
```

The bigger issue is that I can't run pod install, I get:

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/MyTestApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
```

However, I see @react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js in node_modules

For reference, package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyTestApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have an existing project that I want to upgrade, but I get the same error. That's why I decided to try a fresh project. However, I'm getting the same error in the fresh project too.

`pod version = 1.9.1`
`node version = v8.3.0`
`npm version = 5.2.0`

Answer (score 21):

I was having the same problem where I see the file in node module but still giving me same error.

This might sound crazy as it does to me but for some reason I get this error only when I run `pod install` from the VS Code Terminal but when I run this same from MacOS terminal it worked fine and pod were installed.

It may not work for you but worth giving a shot while it worked for me. :)

Comment: I didn't believe this answer at the beginning but gave it a try anyway and yes, it worked :) But i am very curious about how it could be possible :)

Comment: @Nostromo I'm still curious but haven't dig deep to know the root cause. If someone knows, please add the possible reason in comments.

Comment: @Nostromo make sure you don't have your debuggers auto-attach on in vscode

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by [Kieran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073807/cannot-find-module-node-modules-react-native-community-cli-build-bin-js-after-r/62848303#comment113932734_62848303) in another comment, if you use VSCode, make sure you turn disable auto-attach for the vscode debugger.

`cmd + shift + p` -> `Debug: toggle auto attach` -> `disable`

My problem was solved by this.

Also, trying `pod install` outside of vscode in a normal terminal should be working as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite crazy issue, when I tried install pod on MacOs terminal everything worked fine. :)